# How to get list members using index from a comprehension

Tags: python

I have 3 lists. Spam lists, Poetry and authors. I am trying to remove both poetry and authors of the poetry that contain any spam word. I am also trying to remove duplicated poetry along with the author.

I have been able to remove poetry that contains spam and also duplicated poetry. But i haven't been able to remove the author so I can get a list of poetry without spam and duplicates and a list of authors of those poetries.

```py
poetry = ["we are different", "we are different", "we are not different", "This is a dummy poetry", "This is not art"]
spam_list = ["art", "poetry"]
authors = ["james", "peter", "paul", "felix", "chris"]

# Removes any poetry that contains spam. 
h = [sentence for sentence in poetry if not any(spam in sentence.split(' ') for spam in spam_list)]

# Removes duplicates
res = []
for i in h:
    if i not in res:
        res.append(i)
for lis in res:
    print(lis)
```

Expected Output for poetry is: we are different,we are not different
Expected Output for authors : James, Paul

I need the authors for the poetry output.

Comment: I'm not sure how your code works.  Your list of poetry and authors is empty.

Comment: Oh, I made it that way. I'll add them. I didn't feel they were needed.

Comment: can you provide some dummy data along in those lists with expected and actual output so someone may get the idea of what is required..

Comment: I've modified it.

Comment: What logic are you expecting to use to filter the correct names from the authors list? Or to put it another way, how does your code know which authors belong to which sentences?

Comment: That's what I haven't done and that's what I need

Comment: @blockhead You need to create another collection which matches the authors to their sentences and filter that collection based on the output from applying the other conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example:

```
poetry = ["we are different", "we are different", "we are not different", "This is a dummy poetry", "This is not art"]
authors = ["james", "peter", "paul", "felix", "chris"]

spam_list = ["art", "poetry"]

results = []
processed = []
for author, poetry in zip(authors, poetry):
    if poetry not in processed and not any(spam in poetry for spam in spam_list):
        processed.append(poetry)
        results.append((author, poetry))
        
print(results)
```

> [('james', 'we are different'), ('paul', 'we are not different')]

One potential issue is that the result is dependent on the input order.

Comment: It's not an issue, the arrangement is exactly how it should be.